# Stripe V2 PayPal, Afterpay and Affirm Integration

Tags: .net, angularjs, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe v2 on my production site to capture payments. From my research, integrating PayPal, Afterpay, and Affirm with Stripe v2 seems impossible. Therefore, I have to migrate to Stripe v3 for this functionality. Is it possible to integrate them using Stripe v2? Or is migration necessary? If integration with Stripe v2 is possible, are any additional steps required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate these payment methods via a server-side integration without using Stripe.JS at all if you like. You would do this by creating the relevant PaymentMethod ([API Ref link](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_methods/create)) and then creating and confirming a PaymentIntent ([link](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/create)) using that aforementioned PaymentMethod. When you do this, you also set a `return_url` ([link](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-return_url)) -- this will have the response include a `next_action.redirect_to_url.url` property ([link](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-next_action-redirect_to_url-url)) which you pass to your frontend to redirect your customer to the necessary payment method authentication page for them to complete the payment using that payment method type.

The easier route, in my opinion, is to just migrate to Stripe.JS v3, which also gives you better PCI Compliance for card payments ([docs](https://docs.stripe.com/security/guide)).

Comment: So, I followed your steps using Postman. I successfully created a Payment Method. However, when I try to create a payment intent, it keeps giving me this error: 'The payment method type "["affirm"]" is invalid. Please ensure the provided type is activated in your dashboard (https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payments/settings), and your account is enabled for any preview features that you are trying to use.'

When I check the dashboard, it's already enabled.

Comment: You can specify `payment_method_types` and see if that works: https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method_types

Comment: @bismarch yet it worked! After confirming the intent it gives me the URL as you said above, My question is I have scheduled payments is well and I would like to auto charge the person at a given date, How will that work or will it always ask for consent.

Comment: In case of recharging the customer for example affirm's case, will the customer be asked for authentication again and again? What can be used to recharge the person in case of installments? For normal card payments i do have the card information but for affirm we don't ask for anything.

Comment: When i use setup_future_usage  to off_session i get the following error
setup_future_usage` cannot be used with one or more of the values you specified in `payment_method_types`. Please remove `setup_future_usage` or remove these types from `payment_method_types`: [\"affirm\"].

Comment: Afterpay and Affirm only support one-time payments.